# Presenting Validation errors in View, avoiding repetition

Tags: validation, laravel, dry, laravel-blade, laravel-validation

What is the best way to loop through errors from Validator and then present them right after the form element without resorting to lots of `@if` clauses?

This is not rather elegant nor DRY:

```
<input name="name" />
@if (isset($errors['name']))
    <div class="error">{!! $errors['name'] !!}</div>
@endif

<input name="email" />
@if (isset($errors['email']))
    <div class="error">{!! $errors['email'] !!}</div>
@endif

<input name="address" />
@if (isset($errors['address']))
    <div class="error">{!! $errors['address'] !!}</div>
@endif
```

It's this repetition I want to avoid. Is there a way to generate form elements with a PHP array or a package that takes care of this entire process, putting an error div right after the form element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any packages, but I would just create my own macro class similar to HTML builder or Form builder.

In fact, I would probably extend `FormBuilder.php` and add a few additional methods, such as:

```
public function inputWithError($type, $name, $errors, $value = null, $options = array())
{
    $errorString = '';
    if(isset($errors[$name])) {
        $errorString = '<div class="error">{$errors[$name]}</div>';
    }
    return $this->input($type, $name, $value, $options) . $errorString;
}
```

**Note** The FormBuilder package can be found [here](https://github.com/illuminate/html)

**EDIT**

A directory might be:

```
/App/App/ExtendedInput
 |
 +- ExtendedInput.php
 |
 +- ExtendedInputFacade.php
 |
 +- ExtendedInputServiceProvider.php
```

**ExtendedInput.php**

```
use Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder;

class ExtendedInput extends FormBuilder 
{

    public function inputWithError($type, $name, $errors, $value = null, $options = array())
    {
        $errorString = '';
        if(isset($errors[$name])) {
            $errorString = '<div class="error">{$errors[$name]}</div>';
        }
        return $this->input($type, $name, $value, $options) . $errorString;
    }
}
```

**ExtenedInputFacade.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class ExtendedInputFacade extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'extendedInput'; }

}
```

**ExtendedInputServiceProvider.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ExtendedInputServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('ExtendedInput', function()
        {
            return new ExtendedInput;
        });
    }

}
```

**config/app.php**

```
'providers' => [
    'App\App\ExtendedInput\ExtendedInputServiceProvider',
    // ..
],
```

Comment: What is a *macro class*? And where should I put this extended class of mine?

Comment: Macro is a term left over from laravel 4. Taylor split out the HTML and Form builders into their own package (as seen in the link above). In terms of location, I create an app namespace such as \Acme\Macros\ and then place the file in there, perhaps with the name ExtendedFormBuilder.php. You will then need to add it as a provide in your config app file.

Comment: As a Service Provider? Or in the class map? I'm using Laravel 5.

Comment: Service provider, and yes, for L5

Comment: Setting up a service provider can be tricky the first time, make sure to raise another question if you get stuck

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. Mustn't I add facades and aliases for this to work too? Could you give me some instantiation code, that would be really helpful.

Comment: If I had more votes I'd give you more. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i'm not getting it to work, says `App\App\ExtendedInput\ExtendedInputFacade' does not have a method 'inputWithError'`. Should the Facade class really end with "Facade"? None of Laravels default facades do that.

Comment: You don't need to, but it is how Laravels external libraries (like the FormBuilder and HtmlBuilder do). I would highly highly recommend composer install them and follow along as they are official libraries. If you still get stuck, raise another question and link to it from here

Comment: I solved it thanks. Had to hijack the service provider of FormBuilder and HtmlBuilder first because they needed dependencies :)

Answer (score 0):

I usualy do this :

```
<input name="name" />
{{ $errors->first('name', '<div class="error">:message</div>') }}
```

it checks automaticaly if the error exists and display it in consequence.
hope this helps.